# Outgoing calls with Twilio iOS Client

Tags: ios, twilio

I am using the Twilio API and can successfully make outgoing calls to a phone number, but when I try to enter another username to connect to, nothing happens. I have two emulators running (one with the Android quickstart client, with which I can make outgoing calls to another user. I can make calls from the Android client to the iOS client using usernames and it works fine, but when I try to do the same from the iOS client to the Android client, nothing happens. I don't get a crash or anything, I just get the initial sound that it tries to start, then the disconnect sound. Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)dialButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.dialField resignFirstResponder];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"To": self.dialField.text};
    _connection = [_phone connect:params delegate:nil];
}
```

I have searched everywhere I can think of online, but every reference seems to talk only about calls with a phone number. The Twilio API for Android handles this easily, but I cannot figure it out for iOS. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you check the debug console in XCode to see if there were any interesting messages there.  Also, you can adjust the log output from client using `[[TwilioClient sharedInstance] setLogLevel:TC_LOG_DEBUG];`.  I'd also suggest checking the Logs for Programmable voice to see if Client is actually connecting to Twilio.  If it is then I would double check that your TwiML App configured for the Client is returning the right TwiML.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I added the line of code you recommended. I don't understand all of the output, but it does appear it's connecting to Twilio just fine. It does receive a token. Also, I am able to make calls to phone numbers and I can even receive calls from another user (not a phone number), I just can't make outgoing calls to a username that I know is registered and can receive user calls from an Android device using the same Twilio account credentials.

Comment: Some additional information: There is a method in the Twilio API called sendDigits, which only accepts values 0-9 and w (the w creates a pause in the dialing). I can't tell where this method is getting called or how to dial a string instead of digits, but it's almost certainly related to this because I noticed I get emails from twilio every time I try to call a username from the iOS app. The email says there was an error related to  a "Forbidden phone number". So it's trying to interpret my string as a phone number or something like that.

Comment: Hi @DevinRader, where do we set this (`[[TwilioClient sharedInstance] setLogLevel:TC_LOG_DEBUG];`) in the code?

Comment: can you share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much thanks to Zack from Twilio who finally noticed that we just needed to add client: before the username when trying to call a user rather than a phone number (When using the Heroku App for the server setup as instructed in the Quickstart tutorial). Not sure why this is not built into the iOS instructions, but it is to the Android version. I'm just glad to have something that works.

I just have to dial client: then the username right into the dial field and it works. Now I can make any desired programming changes.

Thanks